# Como inserir valores de um campo Select no banco de dados

Tags: html, aplicação-web, ruby-on-rails, formulário, orm

Sou iniciante em Ruby on Rails e estou precisando adicionar um campo Select ao form do cadastro de usuários, para que eu possa adicionar um "Tipo" para o usuário a ser cadastrado. Pretendo popular os campos automaticamente durante a edição e visualização de um registro de usuário.

Estou implementando um sistema para uma Gráfica, que possui os perfis "Usuário", "Diretor" e "Gráfica". Meu Select ficou estruturado da seguinte forma no `_form` do usuário:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :tipo %><br>
  <%= f.select :tipo, ['usuario', 'grafica', 'diretor'] %>
</div>
```

Os valores do select não estão sendo inseridos no banco! Como devo proceder?

Comment: Essa coluna `tipo` é mesmo `tipo` ou é `tipo_id`? Se for `tipo_id` isso precisa ser mudado ali.

Comment: É `tipo` mesmo. `tipo` é um atributo de `Usuarios`.

Comment: Você se importa de [edit] a pergunta incluindo o código do controlador?

Answer (score 3):

Se você estiver usando Rails 4, tem que olhar o strog paramters, se você está permitindo o acesso ao atributo, segue exemplo do método:

```
def your_model_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:tipo)
end
```

Se estiver usando Rails 3, verifique se o atributo está acessível. Um exemplo de select:

```
<%= f.select :email_provider, options_for_select(%w[Provider1 Provider2]) %>
```

Espero ter ajudado, um bom começo é guide do Rails :)

Comment: Era isso mesmo! brigadão ^^

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi é isso que você precisa

```
f.select(:tipo, [['usuario', 'usuario'], ['grafica', 'grafica'], ['diretor', 'diretor'] })
```

Comment: Funcionou juntamente com a modificação dos strong parameters, obrigado!